# Invalid JSON response error using JQuery DataTables with PHP & AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I'm working with DataTables for the first time, and I'm running into issues actually putting the data into the table. I believe I have matched the proper JSON format that DataTables calls for using the ajax option within, however I'm still receiving an "Invalid JSON Response" error on load.

Here's my JS, I have it in a separate file called within the HTML page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#copingTable").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      "url": "overviewdata.php",
      "type": "POST",
      "dataType": "json",
      "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "dataSrc": "data"
    },
    "columns": [
      {"data": "FormID"},
      {"data": "SubmittedBy"},
      {"data": "Email"},
      {"data": "Date"}
    ]
  });
});
```

And my PHP:

```
$storiesSql = "SELECT FormID, CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS SubmittedBy, Email, DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS Date FROM Stories";
  $storiesStmt = $pdo->query($storiesSql);

  $dataArray = array();

  while($row = $storiesStmt->fetch()){
    array_push($dataArray, array("FormID"=>$row['FormID'], "SubmittedBy"=>$row["SubmittedBy"], "Email"=>$row["Email"], "Date"=>$row['Date']));
  }

  echo json_encode(array("data"=>$dataArray));
```

This is the format of the JSON Response I receive (edited to be correct):

```
{"data":[{"FormID":"5e9754efc8aec","SubmittedBy":"Test Test","Email":"adam.weissert@sru.edu","Date":"04\/15\/2020"}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Added in the working code with mapped data source and columns from the answer below

Comment: Are you sure your php script is returning JSON format?

Comment: At least I think so, I based how I formatted it off of [this](https://www.datatables.net/manual/ajax#Data-array-location)

Comment: Check the Response section of the Network tab to see the full response. Maybe there's some HTML or error messages before or after the JSON.

Comment: I meant server side and to make sure it's 100% JSON add this before output `echo ...`: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: Okay, so using the header code this is the format I'm getting: 


`[{"FormID":"5e9754efc8aec"},{"FormID":"5e985dc946c58"},{"FormID":"5e987e6d4ad0e"},{"FormID":"5e988564524cb"}]`

Comment: And it's working now?

Comment: Still getting Invalid JSON Response, it's definitely valid JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, check the format that your PHP script output (**it should be a valid json with all required fields your JS code expect**), then change datatype value to '**json**' value and add contentType in ...**ajax.contentType** field:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#copingTable").DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
      "url": "overview.php",
      "type": "POST",
      "dataType": "json",
      "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "dataSrc": ""
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help! This helped fix the problem :]